# Create order on other Magento Stores using web API

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, magento2, api, web-services

I'm new to Magento. My friend own an E-Commerce Store powered by Magento. I want to place an order on his website using the Magento APIs. Is it possible without using his admin credentials/token?

Is it possible to have another set of credentials that just let me create an order and do nothing else?

I want to learn it for both Magento 1.x as well as 2.x. So please share info about either or both versions you might have.

Comment: Is this Magento 1.9 or Magento2? You have tagged your question with both. There's a big difference between those two.

Comment: I'm new to Magento hence didn't know which to begin with. Is what I'm asking possible on any of Magento versions?

Comment: It's possible with both, but it's very different on both as well. You should first consult which version of Magento you are going to work with.

Comment: Alright Prateek. I am going to modify the question a little to ask for any details you may have. Can you please share little bit detail on any/both of the versions as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to generate OAuth tokens for REST web APIs, which can be revoked by store administrator at any time, no need to share admin credentials. Your token can be restricted to just order management.

Here you can find official documentation for [Magento 1 REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) and for [Magento 2 web APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html). If no restrictions regarding SOAP vs REST, go for REST with OAuth token authentication (there are other authentication mechanisms available as well).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems one way possible but my friend (more like business partner) insists that I create a Magento Extension for this purpose. Any guidelines on getting started with that? Is that a tricky task?